# Filtering deeply within tree

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to prune nodes deeply within a JSON structure and I'm puzzled why `empty` behaves seemingly different from a normal value here.

## Input

```json
[
    {
        "name": "foo",
        "children": [{
            "name": "foo.0",
            "color": "red"
        }]
    },
    {
        "name": "bar",
        "children": [{
            "name": "bar.0",
            "color": "green"
        },
        {
            "name": "bar.1"
        }]
    },
    {
        "name": "baz",
        "children": [{
            "name": "baz.0"
        },
        {
            "name": "baz.1"
        }]
    }
]
```

## Program

`jq '(.[].children|.[])|=if has("color") then . else empty end' foo.json`

## Actual output

```json
[
  {
    "name": "foo",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "foo.0",
        "color": "red"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "bar",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "bar.0",
        "color": "green"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "baz",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "baz.1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

## Expected output

The output I get, except without the `baz.1` child, as that one doesn't have a color.

## Question

Apart from the right solution, I'm also curious why replacing `empty` in the script by a regular value like `42` would replace the children without colors with 42 as expected, but when replacing with `empty`, it looks like the `else` branch doesn't get executed?

Comment: Where did the `baz` child came from? Thats not in the input?

Comment: @0stone0 Sorry, I copied from the wrong file. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.[].children |= map(select(.color))
```

Will remove `children` that does not `has` an `color` so the output becomes:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "foo",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "foo.0",
        "color": "red"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "bar",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "bar.0",
        "color": "green"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "baz",
    "children": []
  }
]
```

###### [Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/vzdkOizU9HS)

---

Regarding *why* your filter does not seem to like `empty`;
This [git issue](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/2051) seems to be the cause, multiple elements with `empty` will fail.

Comment: Sorry I posted the wrong input. With the correct input the problem still appears.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have an idea what's the reason for the differing output in the script I wrote?

Answer (score 1):

There must be a bug with assigning `empty` to multiple paths.

In this case you can use `del` instead:

```
del(.[].children[] | select(has("color") | not))
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/UlJAUB6MQ7c)</sup>

Comment: I've reported it to the jq bug tracker now. Let's see if it really is one, which would surprise me with such a popular tool.

Comment: You're correct that it's a (two-year old) bug (https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/2051), as the jq repo has a maintenance issue (https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/2305).